# ParseQuery WhereEqualTo does not filter?

Tags: c#, parse-platform, xamarin

I'm new to Parse.com and I'm running in to some problems. I am trying to get all records from the database where the boolean `Deleted`equals `false`. This doesn't seem to work in any way though.
For example:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseObject.GetQuery("Horse");
query.WhereEqualTo("Deleted", "false");
IEnumerable<ParseObject> horses = await query.FindAsync();
```

When I run this with three records where two of them are false and one is true I still get all three records..This is my test data:
[image: Demo data] 
I've tried numerous ways for this query such as:

```
query.WhereNotEqualTo("Deleted", "true");
query.WhereNotEqualTo("Deleted", true);
query.WhereEqualTo("Deleted", false);
```

But none of these seem to work. What am I doing wrong? I would love to keep a `Boolean` field and these queries. Another strange thing is when I create my own query and make an integer field for example the search 'filters' do work:

```
var query2 = from gameScore in ParseObject.GetQuery("Horse")
             where gameScore.Get<string>("Removed") == "1"
             select gameScore;
IEnumerable<ParseObject> results = await query2.FindAsync();
```

So why does this work but a `ParseQuery` does not? I'd like to either write a `ParseQuery` that only fetches records that match false or write a query myself that matches this.

**Update:**
Added new query samples per request. Encapsulated value between ""

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseObject.GetQuery("Horse");
query.WhereEqualTo("Deleted", "false");
IEnumerable<ParseObject> horses = await query.FindAsync();
```

Without "" for the false statement:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseObject.GetQuery("Horse");
query.WhereEqualTo("Deleted", false);
IEnumerable<ParseObject> horses = await query.FindAsync();
```

Both of these return all values, even if `Deleted` is true.

Thanks,
Yenthe

Comment: code from github
 
 public ParseQuery<T> WhereEqualTo(string key, object value) {
      return new ParseQuery<T>(this, where: new Dictionary<string, object> {
        {key, value}
      });
    }
 
 
 it creates a new request

Answer (score 0):

If your column is of type `Boolean` then `whereEqualTo("Deleted", false)` and `whereNotEqualTo("Deleted", true)` should work fine. The string version won't work though, or may be converted using "truthy/falsey" logic (though I think that's only JavaScript, not C#).

Try your query again using native C# bool values instead of string.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Timothy. I did try this too and that doesn't work either. This is the code:
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseObject.GetQuery("Horse");
            query.WhereEqualTo("Deleted", false);
            query.WhereNotEqualTo("Deleted", true); and my field is a Boolean. So is this wrong in the API or am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: You should use either `WhereEqualTo` or `WhereNotEqualTo`, but not both. They are slightly different in how they handle null/empty values.

Comment: @Timotyh I did use only one statement. I've first tried WhereEqualTo, then WhereNotEqualTo and then both together but none of them work so this seems as if the API is not working correctly then?

Comment: If you could add a complete query using `WhereEqualTo` that isn't working to your question, that'd be great, as it should work fine.

Comment: I've added two samples, both using WhereEqualTo and both get all values, both when Deleted is true and false.

Answer (score 0):

should W be capitalized in WhereEqualTo()? havent read the api docs but typically camel case is used.

Comment: Yep its with a capital W, as seen here: http://parse.com/docs/dotnet/api/html/M_Parse_ParseQuery_1_WhereEqualTo.htm thanks for the reply though!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your query is that you are not storing the query after adding the additional filter. When adding filters, the query is modified and **returned**, and this returned value needs to be assigned as the new query.

```
...
query = query.WhereEqualTo("Deleted", false);
...
```

Note that you can chain query filters, so your code code be modified as:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseObject.GetQuery("Horse")
    .WhereEqualTo("Deleted", false);
IEnumerable<ParseObject> horses = await query.FindAsync();
```

You can chain as many query filters as you like, as long as the filters don't conflict with each other. (You'll have to check the documentation for compatible filters)

Having to reassign may seem like a strange approach, but I imagine it is so that you can create a single base query with many common filters, and then easily branch off with more niche options:

```
// Create a base query
var baseQuery = new ParseQuery<Horse>();
// Add many common filters

var removedHorses = query.WhereEqualTo("Deleted", true);
var remainingHorses = query.WhereEqualTo("Deleted", false);
var sickHorses = query.WhereEqualTo("Health", "Sick");
// And so on
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseObject.GetQuery("Horse");

IEnumerable<ParseObject> horses = await query.WhereEqualTo("Deleted", "false").FindAsync();
```

It works for me like the example below:

```
ParseQuery<Classes.PermissoesGerenciarMedicos> queryPermissoesMedicos = new ParseQuery<Classes.PermissoesGerenciarMedicos>();
            queryPermissoesMedicos.WhereEqualTo("usuario", ParseUser.CurrentUser as Classes.Usuario).FindAsync().ContinueWith(resultado => {
                if (resultado.IsCompleted && !resultado.IsFaulted)
                {
                    if (resultado.Result.Count() == 1)
                    {
                        permissoesGerenciarMedicos = resultado.Result.ElementAt(0) as Classes.PermissoesGerenciarMedicos;
                        carregaPermissoesUsuarios();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Erro ao carregar as permissões do usuário", "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

                        processandoDadosDelegate processandoDadosD = new processandoDadosDelegate(processandoDados);
                        this.Invoke(processandoDadosD, new object[] { false });
                    }
                } else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Erro ao carregar as permissões do usuário", "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

                    processandoDadosDelegate processandoDadosD = new processandoDadosDelegate(processandoDados);
                    this.Invoke(processandoDadosD, new object[] { false });
                }
            });
```